# How to affect both the next element and the element after

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is presumably quite easy to achieve, but I can't figure out how to do it. I want to, when you hover over the first element, change the opacity of the second and third (make them appear).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fa5r3q18/)

```css
.two{
    opacity:0;
}
.three{
    opacity:0;
}
.one:hover + .two, .one:hover + .three{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class = "one">
    <h1>one</h1>
</div>
<div class = "two"><h1>two</h1></div>
<div class = "three"><h1>three</h1></div>
```

I would then like to have something like this:

```
.one:hover + .two, ++.three{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/ep5gtfje/1/)):

```css
.two {
    opacity: 0;
}

.three {
    opacity: 0;
}

.one:hover ~ .two, .one:hover ~ .three {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class = "one">
    <h1>one</h1>
</div>
<div class = "two">
    <h1>two</h1>
</div>
<div class = "three">
    <h1>three</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` combinator connects two consecutive siblings at a time. In order to reach a sibling that is two steps away, you will accordingly need to use `+` twice, once for each sibling that you step across.

The resulting selector is `.one:hover + .two + .three`.

```css
.two, .three {
  opacity: 0;
}
.one:hover + .two, 
.one:hover + .two + .three {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><h1>one</h1></div>
<div class="two"><h1>two</h1></div>
<div class="three"><h1>three</h1></div>
```

You can also use the `~` combinator but this requires that `.one`, `.two` and `.three` be the only children of the parent element (or at least that the latter two be the only instances of their kind after `.one`), in which case you might as well shorten it to `.one:hover ~ div` rather than target each following sibling separately. Using `+` combinators is more conservative and less error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

```
.one:hover + .two, .one:hover + .three{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but this does not seem to work.